Javascript IntersectionObserver on Inactive Tab?
I tried to use IntersectionObserver to check, when an element (button) is visible.
But when i tab out, so the tab is inactive, he doesnt see it anymore. When i tab in, he sends the console.log found instantly.
Any ideas, if there is a way, to check if the button is visible
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log('found')
    }, {
        root: null,
        threshold: 0.1, // set offset 0.1 means trigger if atleast 10% of element in viewport
})
observer.observe(document.querySelector(el));

I also tried MutationObserver but that cannot check if the button is in view. Just checking if there is code in background. And when its one time there, its there forever, also when its invisible than.
I just want to check if the button can be clicked right now, nothing more. But with MutationObserver he spams found, cause he found the code in background, also when the button is not in view.
I tried to search for someone with the same problem. Also tried mutationObserver but thats not the same.

This is a known (and intentional) behaviour of Chrome. There's nothing you can do in JS to prevent it from happening.

Once try like this
Observe the target element and trigger the callback when the element is at least 10% visible in the viewport.
Listens for when the document's visibility changes (i.e., when the user tabs in or out). When the tab becomes active, it manually checks the element's visibility using its bounding rectangle.
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log('found');
    }
}, {
    root: null,
    threshold: 0.1 // Trigger when at least 10% of the element is in the viewport
});

const targetElement = document.querySelector(el);
observer.observe(targetElement);

// Handle tab visibility change

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    
        // Manually check if the element is visible when the tab becomes active
        const rect = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const isVisible = (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
        );

        if (isVisible) {
            console.log('found');
        }
    }
});

